# How to write file based on row and column

Tags: java, list, text-files, converters

can you help me on my code. I would like to convert List to text.txt and the format should be as below:

```
private List<String>expDelLst =null;   
expDelLst = new ArrayList<String>();
expDelLst = loginCountryBusServ.getExportDetails(userVO.getCtryCd());

FileWriter fos = new FileWriter("c:/data.txt");
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fos);

for (int i = 0; i < expDelLst.size(); i++) {
out.write(StringUtils.join((Object[]) expDelLst.toArray()[i],"|"));
}
out.close();

and the how out put should be as: in text file.
F590|F590|CDG|590|FRDD|ESI|H|FR|GB|||11111111|598|598|T12|2012-12-20 12:10:30|
F590|F590|CDG|590|FRDD|ESU|W|FR|GB|||11111111|598|598|T12|2012-12-20 12:10:30|
F590|F590|CDG|590|FRDD|ESI|H|FR|FR|CDG|102|11111111|LF2|LF2|T33|2012-12-20 12:15:32|
F590|F590|CDG|590|FRDD|ESU|W|FR|FR|CDG|102|11111111|LF2|LF2|T33|2012-12-20 12:15:32|
F590|F590|CDG|590|FRDD|ESI|H|FR|FR|TLS|335|11111111|LF2|LF2|T57|2012-12-20 12:18:32|
F590|F590|CDG|590|FRDD|ESU|W|FR|FR|TLS|335|11111111|LF2|LF2|T57|2012-12-20 12:18:32|
F590|F590|CDG|590|FRDD|ESI|H|FR|FR|CDG|102|11111111|LF2|T33|B08|2012-12-20 12:25:52|
F590|F590|CDG|590|FRDD|ESU|W|FR|FR|CDG|102|11111111|LF2|T33|B08|2012-12-20 12:25:52|
```

Comment: what is the problem with the current code? what are the contents of ArrayList?

Comment: Yes please be specific what is problem in current code.

Comment: i able to fetch value from the list but the value display as F590|F590|CDG|590|FRDD|ESI|H|FR|GB|||11111111|598|598|T12|2012-12-2012:10:30F590|F590|CDG|590|FRDD|ESU|W|FR|GB|||11111111|598|598|T12|2012-12-2012:10:30 but i wanted the list print based on row and column as i mentioned as example above.

Comment: I *love it* if people write arbitrary text files to the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

How about [FileUtils.writeLines((File file,Collection lines)](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeLines%28java.io.File,%20java.util.Collection%29)

Comment: This will work for any file on your file system. Just use the complete file path.